# Regex - Match a string pattern

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will match only strings of this kind

Match these strings:

```
edo-apple-iphone-5s-i-gold-16
```

DON'T match these strings:

```
edo-apple-iphone-5s-i-gold-16-edo-staff-connect-24
```

The main difference between the 2 strings is either a `connect-24` OR `handset-24` added to the end of the string

I have written a Regex, but it seems to match both strings:

```
^edo[a-z1-9\-]*
```

How do i modify this to not accept if `connect-24` OR `handset-24` is in the string?

Comment: Can you post what you've written?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what the difference between the sets is?

Comment: Perhaps something like this? `^edo-apple-iphone-5s-i-gold-16-(edo-(staff|team)-connect|map-(130|95)-handset)-24$`?

Comment: @DavidFaber: Can you modify the script i have to exclude 24

Answer (score 1):

The regex that matches the requirements: Not accept if connect-24 OR handset-24 is in the string

```
^(?:(?!connect-24|handset-24).)*$
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/iE1nD8/4)

Comment: Is this based on the length of the string?

Comment: @DeepaAranha The old regex partly dependend on the length of the string - the new one doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that would satisfy the requirement as stated:

```
.{32,}
```

Clearly, the strings you want to match are all longer than the ones you don't want to match. This regex matches only those strings that are 32 characters or longer, while `edo-apple-iphone-5c-i-yellow-32`, the longest non-matching string, has only 31 characters.

Comment: Thank you for that. However this will not help. I need to have a regex string that will only accept a string that does not have 24 in it

Comment: That's helpful information, but also contradicts what you wrote above. The four strings you want to match above all have `24` in them.